# react-native-scrollable-tab-view not scroll in scrollView tag

Tags: react-native

i want to use react-native-scrollable-tab-view for tab navigation in my code and im use Scrollview for scroll in but not working.

```
 return(

                <ScrollView
                    contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
                >
                    {this.renderHeader()}
                    <View style={styles.baner}/>
                    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <ScrollableTabView
                            initialPage={2}
                            tabBarBackgroundColor={them.white}
                            tabBarActiveTextColor={them.black}
                            tabBarInactiveTextColor={them.borderColor}
                            tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor:them.green}}
                        >
                            <MyRequest name='tab1' tabLabel='درخواستهای من' />
                            <Requests name='tab2' tabLabel='درخواست‌ها' />
                            < Suggestion name='tab3' tabLabel='پیشنهادها' />
                            <Message  name=' tab4' tabLabel='پیام ها' />
                        </ScrollableTabView>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>

            )
```